# typeid of template parameter universal reference

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there some way I can output if the template parameter is an rvalue reference, reference, or constant value? That is, I'm using a universal reference and would, for debugging/learning purposes, like to see exactly which type actually matched.

```
template<typename T>
void write( T && f ) {
    std::cout << typeid(f).name;
}
```

This of course doesn't show me that it was an rvalue, lvalue, or const parameter which was passed. I would like somehow to display which parameter type was actually matched. Note that I'm specifically interested in seeing how this single function is matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the `type_traits` header. It has traits for detecting if a type is `const` and if it is an `reference`.
You can check `T` to see what kind of reference you have bound:

1. If `f` is of laval-reference-type, then so is `T`
2. If `f` is `const` then so is `T`
3. If `f` is an rvalue-reference, then `T` is not an reference (if bound by argument deduction at least).

So you could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void write( T && f ) {
    std::cout << "f is a " <<(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value?"const ":"")<<(std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value?"lvalue":"rvalue")<<" reference";
}
```

Comment: 'is_const' doesn't appear to ever say true in this case: http://ideone.com/ha3UNS

Comment: I believe it should be `is_const<remove_reference<T>::type>::value>`

Comment: @Angew: Ah you are right forgot about that. I will change my answer to match

Comment: @Angew sweet, just: `is_const<typename remove_reference<T>::type>::value>` (missing "typename")
@edA-qa mort-ora-y you forgot the `::type` part

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: `std::remove_reference<T>` gives you the trait itself, you need `std::remove_reference<T>::type` (and `typename`, since it is a dependent type).